# Disable image caching of sub directories using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to disable caching for images in sub directories.

```
Folder
.htaccess
 --Img-dir1 - don't cache
 --Img-dir2 - don't cache
 --Img-dir3 - don't cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another .htaccess in the images subdirectories with

`ExpiresActive off`

Comment: Can't I add just one `.htaccess` file which will affect the subdirectories? I know about `ExpiresActive off` ... I just want to have one `.htaccess` file.

Comment: You could also try using [directory match](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directorymatch) and then setting `Header set Expires` to a past date.